# Quadratic residue $a \pmod{pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $n = pq$, where $p, q$ are odd prime numbers.

- How prove that the equation $x^2 \equiv a \pmod n$, where $a$ is invertible, $a \in \Bbb Z_n$, either has $4$ different solutions or is not solvable?
- Prove that for irreversible residue $c\ne 0$, $c \in \Bbb Z_n$ satisfying the equation $x^2 \equiv c \pmod n$ has $2$ different solutions?

Any suggestions are welcome!
I thought about using Euler's criterion [Euler's criterion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1PvX.png), but it doesn't really help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Well, If $a$ is arrevertable, then we have a system $x^2 = a(mod p) $ and $x^2 = a(mod q)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese remainder theorem
$$
\mathbb{Z}/(n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p) \times \mathbb{Z}/(q)
$$
where the isomorphism is induced by the map $x \mapsto (x,x)$. This means that finding a solution of $x^2\equiv a$ (mod $n$) is equivalent to finding pairs $(u,v)$ such that $u^2\equiv a$ (mod $p$) and $v^2 \equiv a$ (mod $q$).

I don't want to solve your whole exercise, so think about the following questions

- How many solutions of $x^2\equiv a$ (mod $p$) are there ?
- What do you know about $x$ if $x^2$ is not invertible (mod $n$) ?
- If you have $i$ solutions (mod $p$), and $j$ solutions (mod $q$), then how many solutions do you have (mod $pq$) ?

Comment: I understand that $x^2\equiv a (mod p)$ has 2 or 0 solutions. And that if I have $i$ solutions $mod p$ and $j$ $mod q$ than I have $i*j$ solutions $mod(p*q)$. The question is why $gcd(a,n)=1$ is so important?

Comment: Actually there is a case when $x^2\equiv a$ (mod $p$) has just 1 solution. Finding out what that case is is connected to the fact that we need $\gcd (a,n)=1$. And it will also give you an answer for the non-invertible $c$.
As for the number of solutions being $i\cdot j$ that is correct, so you're on good track !